# GTX 1060 error 43 on a brand new notebook (Solved)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, gpu

SOLVED reason: It turned out that the motherboard was defective. REGARDLESS, those of you who need help resolving the issue, try the things that I did. At all the forums that I looked into there were plenty of people that said that those options worked for them.

I've spent about 15 hours so far trying to resolve an error 43 on my brand new MSI GE62VR 7RF. The error has been present from the moment I installed Windows on it. I've looked though who knows how many pages and posts and I've tried a lot of things, not one of them helped. Here's what I tried:

1. Using DDU in safe mode to remove the divers; restart; install it with a downloaded installer and the internet off
2. Reinstalling windows
3. Opening the notebook itself, removing the battery, then holding the Start key for 60+ seconds to discharge any static (I read about this in several different posts)
4. Reinstalled the firmware
5. Flashed the BIOS with a new version (I got the files from MSI and followed their instructions)
6. Tried uninstalling, rebooting, and installing the drivers from the Device Manager
7. Tried disabling the driver and re-enable it
8. I even found a way to force the GTX on and off the device manager by toggling "Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901" in the "System devices". It fails to get it to work
9. I disabled the Intel GPU (there's another GPU but it's not the main one, for obvious reasons) and tried to get the GTX to work. The reason why I tried this was because in a post I read that Windows selects a GPU and sticks with it, making the other one cause errors, which makes Windows shut it down. I don't know if it's even possible, but this solution was of no help
10. Removing all video drivers in safe mode
11. Tried installing older versions of the drivers

**What I can't do or haven't tried:**

1. Removing the GPU. It's built in. I can't remove it.

**What I know for sure:**

1. The GTX's fans are working
2. Installing the drivers from nVidia works until I restart, when it tells me that there are new drivers available for me. This goes on perpetually
3. When I remove the drivers with DDU and keep the Ethernet cable off, Windows installs some basic drivers (Microsoft Basic Display Driver) but this gives this error:

   > This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the
   >   drivers required for this device. (Code 31)
   >
   > The driver trying to start is not the same as the driver for the
   >   POSTed display adapter.
4. The GeForce thing recognizes the card

I have no idea what else I can try. At this point the only answer that I have is that the video card itself is faulty. If anyone else has any ideas, please tell me! D: I need my laptop. I know it's designed for games, but I've got a diploma to finish and that diploma has 3D rendering that needs to be done.

Comment: Rather than editing the original question, consider positing the solution as an answer and accepting it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what you tried:

- In the BIOS - check in the video section if there is something that implies performance optimization (it's called Optimus on Dells, I'm not sure of the name in MSIs). If it is, disable it.
- For windows: install it via the official MS ISO image. Once installed, force it to update completely. Once that is done, get the nV 378.49 driver. Do not install any other drivers at this point. (If windows does not comply with it's installation because it used a newer one when updating you will have to remove the current one and then install the 378.49, but that should not happen for now.)
- While doing previous step, make sure the card is not connected to any other external things (monitors, TVs).

If the above is not good either, then there are two options left: either there's a conflict between integrated GPU and the card (I encountered this a few times and there are no actual solutions at this point - nV will have to fix the driver conflict - in your case it manifests a lot worse than the average/ BSOD/restarts)  or the card is actually bad (in which case you should test it on another system).

Comment: I tried those things, it didn't work. I think there's a physical problem with the card itself. I'll go to an after service centre and see what they will say. Hope it won't cost me a bunch more : /